# Windsor Castle: Hooking up to container's resolving and releasing mechanism

Tags: castle-windsor, listener, eventaggregator

I'm trying to implement **automatic registration of my listeners to a singleton event aggregator when listeners are created by the IoC container** - basically what Jeremy D. Miller is doing, but with Castle instead of StructureMap.

So I want to be able to "intercept" Windsor's object creation mechanism and, if the object supports the marker interface (let's say `IListener`), call the `Subscribe` method to an `EventAggregator` (which is also registered in the container) to make the newly created object a subscriber to events. Also, before the object instance has been released by the container, I want to be able to unsubscribe it.

I'm a little bit confused about what mechanism in Windsor Castle I should use to achieve something like this? I started looking at `IInterceptor` interface, but it seems to intercept **all** calls to the object, which is not what I really need (and want to avoid for performance reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IKernel` exposes various events](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/InversionOfControl/Castle.MicroKernel/IKernelEvents.cs) like `ComponentCreated` and `ComponentDestroyed` which you can use to build that. There are [many samples](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=container.kernel.componentcreated+windsor) on the web.

Otherwise you could just use the [event wiring facility](http://www.google.com/search?q=windsor+event+wiring), but it's not convention based.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use OnCreate like this:

```
container.Register(
        Component.For(typeof (Foo)).OnCreate(
          (k, c) => {
            // ...
            eventAggregator.Subscribe(c);
            // ...
          }));
```